# __attribute__((packed)) on a struct with only 1 element

Tags: c++

I am going through some legacy code developed by a super star no longer working with the firm. All through his code he has packed structs. However I see him doing this for structure members with only 1 element as well. I am not sure if there are any benefits for him doing things this way. Am I missing something?

Sample code:

```
struct A { 
    uint32_t a __attribute__((packed));
};
```

Comment: Packing structs as a matter of course is not a good idea. You are trading memory consumption for execution time, but it's usually a very bad trade, unless you're on a *severely* memory-constrained system.

Comment: @Cody Gray I mostly agree with your comment. However, it sometimes makes sense to pack structs if you need to know the exact layout - for instance if you need to transfer it over a network and need to know how to unpack/parse it on the other side.

Comment: @jesper Maybe, but I don't find that very convincing. Packing creates endianness problems, which makes it not so good for portability. Besides, when you're transferring data over a network, you will need some kind of protocol, and so that protocol should deal with the differences. Perhaps you are thinking of *binary* compatibility, where you serialize a structure to disk? That is the definition of unportable, and I would say is not a good idea, either. Not when you're designing an API at least. Obviously the compiler extension has to exist for compatibility reasons with third-party APIs.

Comment: @Cody Gray I'm not disagreeing with you, it's not the best argument ever. I was simply trying to give one example where packing might make sense other than as a space/performance tradeoff. I'm *not* saying you should design things to require the need for packing!

Comment: I work on low latency trading systems. One aspect of our job is to keep the network payload as small as possible. This is the area where we usually pack our structures

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the target architecture, and it would mostly affect arrays. For a 32 bit architecture, your example will really have no effect. On the other hand, for a 64 bit architecture, without the packed attribute the compiler *might* align entries in an array of struct A to 64 bits, leaving a 32 bit gap between each entry.

Unless you're facing serious memory constraints, it's a probably a bad idea.

Eric Raymond's ["The Lost Art of C Structure Packing"](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/) is a very worthwile read on this topic.

Comment: You get a +1 for the link :)

Comment: Yup that's it. Sorry didn't think about arrays when I was looking through the code